# Handling 2 POST requests through same route with Flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, post

I am attempting to handle 2 different POST requests that are on the same page. The code I currently have handles the `meterID = request.form.get('add_meterId')` properly, but in the else clause, `meterID = request.form.get('del_meterId')` returns a Nonetype when a value is submitted. Below is the python code as well as the html code for the 2 POST requests. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
@auth.route('/manage-meters', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def manage_meters():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form["form-group"]=="add_meterId":
        meterID = request.form.get('add_meterId')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.manage_meters'))
    else:
        meterID = request.form.get('del_meterId')
        return redirect(url_for('auth.manage_meters'))


<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="left">
        <h4>Add Meter ID</h4>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="add_meterId"></label>
                <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="add_meterId"
                        name="add_meterId"
                        placeholder="Enter Meter ID #">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="form-group" value="add_meterId">Add Meter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
    <section class="right">
        <h4>Remove Meter ID</h4>
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="del_meterId"></label>
                <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control"
                        id="del_meterId"
                        name="del_MeterId"
                        placeholder="Enter Meter ID #">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="form-group" value="del_meterId">Remove Meter</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form field is named `del_MeterId`, while you're attempting to retrieve `del_meterId` - see the difference in caps. Use the same value. Another tip is to not look at which button is being used, instead check whether the value (i.e. just check if `.get('del_meterId' has a value) is present or not; buttons might only be included if they're the reason why the form is being submitted (so pressing enter in the input box might not include the button's value.

Answer (score 0):

After changing the field name differences that @MatsLindh pointed out I also changed the if clause to:
`if request.method == 'POST' and "add_meterId" in request.form:`,
which seemed to fix the issue.